# Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 12 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server

Fairly new to SQL Server and I'm struggling to understand why this date conversion doesn't work when I use it in a temp table. For some reason it works when i use it without the temp table.

The database contains dates in the format of `YYYYMMDD`.

```
[DOB] = CAST(LEFT(DC.DATE_BIRTH,8) AS DATE),
```

I get this error :

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Thanks!

Comment: Please include an actual example that reproduces the error. date_birth appears to be a *string* not a *date*.

Comment: Seems like your column contains string values that are only mostly formatted like YYYYMMDD. You'll get that error message when they deviate from that exact format, e.g.: `select cast('2021-12-' as date)`. Is there a reason why the `DATE_BIRTH` column isn't actually using the `date` data type?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you store dates in columns of type `DATE`, not `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Thank you. For your responses. I unfortunately have no control over the database. For whatever reason unfortunately the date is stored as string !

Comment: Unfortunately, the use of varchar to store dates has allowed invalid values to be stored and you will need to cleanse your table of invalid values or otherwise avoid them in your queries. This always happens - a lesson to learn. You can use TRY_CAST() to work around the error.

Comment: Run this SQL to see which values it can't convert to a date: SELECT DC.DATE_BIRTH FROM YourTableName WHERE TRY_CAST(LEFT(DC.DATE_BIRTH,8) AS DATE) IS NULL

Comment: Thank you @Paul. The column had null values which when unselected solved my problem. I love Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to your data on DC.DATE_BIRTH table. check your date. I suppose that in some rows on this table exist the rows that when you trim it whith 8 characters, the remain part is not as a correct date format.